# SHACL to compare values on two different nodes?

Tags: rdf, shacl

I am trying to write a SHACL constraint for a date comparison where the start date must be less than or equal to an end date.  When the dates are attached to the same node using the `:beginDate` and `:endDate` predicates, the constraint is straight forward:

```
:StartEndRuleShape a :PropertyShape  ;
  sh:path              :beginDate ;
  sh:lessThanOrEquals  :endDate ;
  sh:message "Begin Date is after End Date." .
```

The real world model is more complex. In the attached diagram, note how an `:AnimalSubject` `hasReferenceInterval`. ReferenceInterval IRIs have a `:ReferenceBegin` and a `:ReferenceEnd`, which are in turn assigned the date value using the `time:inXSDDate` predicate. How can I apply the constraint in this case to ensure the ReferenceBegin value is equal to or less than ReferenceEnd value? Is this a case for using SHACL-SPARQL, or sequencePath ?  I've been unable to find good examples of either.
Cheers!
[image]

I tested the following SHACL-SPARQL on data that violates the constraint: ReferenceBegin = "2016-12-07", ReferenceEnd = "2016-12-06", but the Validation Report does not detect the violation. If I run the SPARQL on its own, it does pick out the observation. Any thoughts on why? I am using Stardog/Stardog Studio and have also posted on their user support platform.

```
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix sh:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix time: <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#> .
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix :     <http://foo.bar.org/> .

:IntervalShape a sh:NodeShape ;
 sh:targetClass :ReferenceInterval ;
 sh:sparql [
  a sh:SPARQLConstraint ;
  sh:message "End Date must be greater than or equal to Begin Date";
  sh:prefixes [
    sh:declare [
      sh:prefix "time" ;
      sh:namespace "http://www.w3.org/2006/time#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    ] 
  ] ;
 sh:select
  """SELECT $this (?beginDate AS ?intervalStart) (?endDate AS ?intervalEnd)
    WHERE {
      $this     :hasReferenceInterval ?interval .
      ?interval :ReferenceBegin       ?beginIRI ;
                :ReferenceEnd         ?endIRI .
      ?beginIRI time:inXSDDate        ?beginDate .
      ?endIRI   time:inXSDDate        ?endDate .
      FILTER  (! (?endDate >= ?beginDate ))
    }""" ;
] .
```

Comment: Not a full response, but this sounds like SHACL-SPARQL to me. Even if the values could be reached with a path expression, the values of sh:lessThanOrEquals can only be simple properties, not paths.

Comment: I agree, Holger.  I tried this SHACL-SPARQL but it does not detect the violation in a record where I set a ReferenceBegin of "2017-12-07" and a ReferenceEnd of "2017-12-06".  I will update my post with the SHACL-SPARQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your constraint has two issues:

1. You declare the `time` prefix in your SHACL, but not the `base` prefix. You want:

   ```
   sh:prefixes [
       sh:declare [
         sh:prefix "time" ;
         sh:namespace "http://www.w3.org/2006/time#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
       ], [
         sh:prefix "" ;
         sh:namespace "http://foo.bar.org/"^^xsd:anyURI ;
       ]
     ] ;
   ```
2. Your focus node is `:ReferenceInterval`, however the way your query is written, `$this` will only ever be bound to entities that `:hasReferenceInterval [a :ReferenceInterval]`. I rewrote the query so that `?interval` is now `$this` as follows:

   ```
   sh:select
     """SELECT $this (?beginDate AS ?intervalStart) (?endDate AS ?intervalEnd)
       WHERE {
         $this     :ReferenceBegin       ?beginIRI ;
                   :ReferenceEnd         ?endIRI .
         ?beginIRI time:inXSDDate        ?beginDate .
         ?endIRI   time:inXSDDate        ?endDate .
         FILTER  (! (?endDate >= ?beginDate ))
       }""" ;
   ```

   Adding this constraint, I was able to see a violation.